# Nodes with many relationships

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Imagine that there's a node NN with **many** relationships called B..Z.

And NN has one relationship A.

If I were to cypher:

```
MATCH(nn:NN_TYPE) where ...
MATCH(nn)-[:A]->(m)
RETURN m
```

Would this query be unduly slowed down by the multitude of other relations on NN?

Comment: Do you mean that `nn` has relationships of many different *types*, but only one of type `A`? (By the way, nodes do not have "types" -- they have "labels".)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it wouldn't the relationships are stored separately on disk and also in memory.

So it would only load the type :A in your case not the :B ones.